# How to introduce a trigger word for 'quiet' in the car?

Tags: toddler, behavior, teaching, driving

I've been reading a parenting book which has a section about entertaining a toddler in a car. It acknowledges that you sometimes need to concentrate when driving and it has the following suggestion:

> ... have a trigger word that tells them you need them to be quiet straight away. In our car, that word is 'maps'.

My question is, how can I introduce such a trigger word?

Note: I think it is important for the trigger word training to be positive, i.e. avoid punishment or negative associations when teaching for the trigger word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rewards**

Classically, you explain the rule to your kid and give them a reward every time they get it right. When you feel that the trigger is "embodied", you slowly but surely **suppress rewards**.  The link between trigger and reflex disappears but the reflex stays: the trigger is learnt.
Technically speaking, it's called [classical conditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning) (and *no*, it does *not* mean taking your child for a dog) !

Now, this has a downside: your kid is quite smart so it probably won't take it that you suppress rewards.  Using a wording similar to yours, it's not a *negative* training (giving the stick) but it has an *indirectly negative* part (not giving the carrot).

As an alternative, I'd suggest instead what one could call "child-oriented conditioning": you use their wishes as a reward.
It goes somewhere along those lines:

1. Your kid comes to you with a request (go play outside, get a candy, can I have a little sister or whatever).
2. "Sure but let's play our little game first, okay?"  You give the trigger, they show the expected reaction so they get their reward: what *they* asked for in the first place.
3. Repeat over and over, possibly every time they come to you with a new request.
4. When you feel that the trigger is "embodied", you slowly but surely **stop asking for it** when they come to you with a request.  They simply get what they want (or not), like before.

See the difference (bold emphasis)?
Instead of *taking* their reward away, you stop *asking* for a reward in return. This turns the indirectly negative part into an *indirectly positive* one (not setting a condition in exchange for the carrot anymore).